# Getting the source code of a page and assigning its content

Tags: php

I am parsing the source code of a web page like this:

```
    private function readPage() {
        header("Content-type: text/plain"); 
        $this->pageSource = @readfile ($this->page);    
    }
```

But it seems as if I can't assign the content into the "pageSource" variable. Where it my mistake?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile) reads a file and outputs it to STDOUT. I think you're probably looking for [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents).